# Checking Normality of Numerical and Categorical Data

Tags: ordinal-data, normality-assumption, computational-statistics, exploratory-data-analysis, variable

I have come across 3 questions on the title subject.

1. **Why is it necessary to do a normality test?** To check if data is imbalanced or not?
2. Are these 4 methods of checking if the data follows normal distribution criteria **both applicable to numerical and categorical variable?** 
   I am trying to check if the data follows normal distribution by the following 4 methods.

   1. Checking Distribution
   2. Drawing Box Plot
   3. Drawing QQ Plot
   4. Use skewness, kurtosis criteria
3. **Skewness** for normal distribution is 0, **Kurtosis** for normal distribution is 3. Is there a **certain bound that I can use** to guarantee that the data is normally distributed? (such as, 0 +/- 1 OR 3 +/- 1)