# Checking Normality of Numerical, and Categorical Data

Tags: r, normal-distribution, exploratory-data-analysis, feature-selection

I have come across 3 questions on the title subject.

1. **Why is it necessary to do a normality test?** To check if data is imbalanced or not?
2. Are these 4 methods of checking if the data follows normal distribution criteria **both applicable to numerical and categorical variable?** I am trying to check if the data follows normal distribution by following 4 methods.

   1. Checking Distribution
   2. Drawing Box Plot
   3. Drawing QQ Plot
   4. Use skewness, kurtosis criteria
3. Skewness for Normal Dist is 0, Kurtosis for Normal Dist is 3. Is there a **certain bound that I can use** to guarantee that the data is normally distributed? (such as, 0 +/- 1 OR 3 +/- 1)

Comment: Duplicate of [this Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462647/checking-normality-of-numerical-and-categorical-data/462660#462660) My attempt to answer is there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking Normality of Numerical, and Categorical Data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462647/checking-normality-of-numerical-and-categorical-data)

Comment: I query the premise of the title. Is it even advisable, let alone necessary, to actually *test* normality?  See, for example, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless

Comment: If a variable is categorical in any strong sense, then being normal is impossible and irrelevant any way.

Answer (score 8):

1) Some statistical tests are exact only if data are a random sample from a normal population. So it can be important to check whether samples are consistent with having come from a normal population. Some frequently used tests, such as t tests, are tolerant of certain departures from normality, especially when sample sizes are large.

Various tests of normality ($H_0:$ normal vs $H_a:$ not normal) are in use. We illustrate Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk tests below. They are often useful, but not perfect:

- If sample sizes are small these tests
  tend not to reject samples from populations that are nearly symmetrical and lack long tails.
- If sample sizes are very large these tests
  may detect departures from normality that are unimportant for practical purposes. [I don't know what you mean by 'imbalanced'.]

2) For normal data, **Q-Q plots** tend to plot data points in almost a straight line. Some sample points with smallest and largest values may stray farther from the line than points between the lower and upper quartiles. Fit to a straight line is usually better for larger samples. Usually, one uses Q-Q plots (also called 'normal probability plots') to judge normality by eye---perhaps without doing a formal test.

*Examples:* Here are Q-Q plots from R statistical software of a small standard uniform sample, a moderate sized standard normal sample, and a large
standard exponential sample. Only the normal sample shows
a convincing fit to the red line. (The uniform sample does not
have enough points to judge goodness-of-fit.)

```
set.seed(424)
u = runif(10);  z = rnorm(75);  x = rexp(1000)   
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  qqnorm(u); qqline(u, col="red")
  qqnorm(z); qqline(z, col="red")
  qqnorm(x); qqline(x, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

[In R, the default is to put data values on the vertical axis (with the option to switch axes); many textbooks and some statistical software put data values on the horizontal axis.]

The null hypothesis for a **Kolmogorov-Smirnov test** is that data come from a *specific* normal distribution--with known values for
$\mu$ and $\sigma.$

*Examples:* The first test shows that sample `z` from above is consistent with sampling from $\mathsf{Norm}(0, 1).$ The second illustrates that the KS-test can be used with distributions other than normal. Appropriately, neither test rejects.

```
ks.test(z, pnorm, 0, 1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  z
D = 0.041243, p-value = 0.999
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(x, pexp, 1)

        One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x
D = 0.024249, p-value = 0.5989
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The null hypothesis for a **Shapiro-Wilk** test is that data come from *some* normal distribution, for which $\mu$ and $\sigma$ may be unknown. Other good tests for the same general hypothesis are in frequent use.

*Examples:* The first Shapiro-Wilk test shows that sample `z` is consistent with sampling from some normal distribution. The second test shows good fit for a larger sample from a different normal distribution.

```
shapiro.test(z)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  z
W = 0.99086, p-value = 0.8715

shapiro.test(rnorm(200, 100, 15)) 

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  rnorm(200, 100, 15)
W = 0.99427, p-value = 0.6409
```

---

*Addendum on the **relatively low power of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test,*** prompted by @NickCox's comment. We took $m = 10^5$ simulated datasets of size $n = 25$ from each of three distributions: standard uniform, ('bathtub-shaped') $\mathsf{Beta}(.5, .5),$ and standard exponential populations. The null hypothesis in each case is
that data are normal with population mean and SD matching
the distribution simulated (e.g., $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=1/2, \sigma=\sqrt{1/8})$ for the beta data).

Power (rejection probability) of the K-S test (5% level) was $0.111$ for uniform, $0.213$ for beta, and $0.241$ for exponential. By contrast, power for the Shapiro-Wilk, testing the null
hypothesis that the population has some normal distribution (level 5%), was
$0.286, 0,864, 0.922,$ respectively.

The R code for the exponential datasets is shown below. All power values for both tests and each distribution are likely accurate to within about $\pm 0.002$ or $\pm 0.003.$

```
set.seed(425); m = 10^5; n=25
pv = replicate(m, shapiro.test(rexp(n))$p.val)
mean(pv < .05); 2*sd(pv < .05)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.9216
[1] 0.001700049
set.seed(425)
pv = replicate(m, ks.test(rexp(25), pnorm, 1, 1)$p.val)
mean(pv < .05); 2*sd(pv < .05)/sqrt(m)
[1] 0.24061
[1] 0.002703469
```

Neither test is very useful for distinguishing a uniform sample of size $n=25$ from normal. Using the S-W test, samples of this size from populations with more distinctively nonnormal shapes are detected as nonnormal with reasonable power.

---

A **boxplot** is not really intended as a way to check for normality. However, boxplots do show outliers. Normal distributions extend in theory to $\pm\infty,$ even though values
beyond $\mu \pm k\sigma$ for $k = 3$ and especially $k = 4$ are quite rare. Consequently, *very many extreme outliers* in a boxplot may indicate
nonnormality--especially if most of the outliers are in the same tail.

*Examples:* The boxplot at left displays the normal sample `z`. It shows a symmetrical distribution and there happens to be one near outlier. The plot at right displays dataset `x`; it is characteristic of exponential samples of this size to show many
high outliers, some of them extreme.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  boxplot(z, col="skyblue2")
  boxplot(x, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

The 20 boxplots below illustrate that normal samples of size 100
often have a few boxplot outliers. So seeing a few near outliers in a boxplot is not to be taken as a warning that data may not be normal.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(20*100, 100, 15)
g = rep(1:20, each=100)
boxplot(x ~ g, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

More specifically, the simulation below shows that, among normal samples of size $n = 100,$
about half show at least one boxplot outlier and the average
number of outliers is about $0.9.$

```
set.seed(2020)
nr.out = replicate(10^5, 
         length(boxplot.stats(rnorm(100))$out))
mean(nr.out)
[1] 0.9232
mean(nr.out > 0)
[1] 0.52331
```

Sample **skewness** far from $0$ or sample **kurtosis** far from $3$ (or $0)$ can indicate nonnormal data. (See Comment by @NickCox.) The question is how far is too far. Personally, I have not found sample skewness and kurtosis to be more useful than other methods discussed above. I will let people who favor using these descriptive measures as normality tests explain how and with what success they have done so.

Comment: Kurtosis is 3 for a normal, except that many programs subtract 3 any way, in which case it is 0 for a normal. So, people need to look at the documentation for explanations of procedure. If that fails, better than nothing is to simulate from a normal and see how kurtosis turns out. A value of 1 isn't a reference level either way. I agree that quantile plots are by far the best place to start, Of the tests mentioned here, Shapiro-Wilk is greatly preferable to Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

Comment: Hundreds of threads here on this. Poor or incorrect advice in many books or internet sources doesn't help. This is difficult territory for the learner. Reasons include (as also explained here) 1. Why is normality being checked for any way? There are several myths e.g. that you need marginal normal distributions for regression. 2. A test can reject normality for reasons that won't bite (minor deviations in a large sample) while small samples are often unclear either way. Nothing is fail safe. 3. Researchers  need to build up experience as well as apply formal procedures.

Comment: Skewness and kurtosis have _some_ descriptive use. For example, if a researcher has thousands of samples, looking at thousands of graphs may not be practical, but skewness and kurtosis can identify wild samples for further checks. L-moments are often as helpful as moment-based measures, but seemingly little used outside a few fields such as hydrology and climatology.

Comment: @NickCox: Thanks for all 3 comments. Fixed error on kurtosis.

Comment: @NickCox: Simulation-based addendum prompted by your mention of poor power of K-S relative to S-W.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of instructors recommend testing for normality because that is what they were taught to do. The practical implications are often quite different. We test for normality because the test statistics, and their resulting distributions, were derived under the assumption that the data is normally distributed.

In many circumstances the Central Limit Theorem will overcome almost any "departure" from normality because the tests rely more on the sampling distribution of the sample mean to be normal than the original data. As a rough rule of thumb, as long as the data is approximately symmetric and unimodal, then the test or method will perform quite well. This is why, for example, regression where *y* is integer valued (with a moderate range in values) can work quite well, even though by definition, *y* is clearly not normal.

Normality can matter if you are interested in prediction for new values, rather than inference for the mean. But most of the time, the importance of normality is completely over-emphasised.

Comment: Duplicate of [this Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462647/checking-normality-of-numerical-and-categorical-data/462660#462660) My attempt to answer is there. Hope your answer doesn't get lost. (+1)